# compile rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ubuntu 14.04 indigo ros.

I install from ros wiki with desktop-full.

I am trying to install rosjava.

using this site:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/indigo/Installation

Source Installation

i am getting errors:

```
[100%] Built target gradle-zeroconf_jmdns_suite

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':rosjava:compile'.
> Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_messages:rosjava_test_msgs:[0.2,0.3).
  Required by:
      org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.2.0
> Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_messages:rosgraph_msgs:[1.10,1.11).
  Required by:
      org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.2.0
> Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_messages:geometry_msgs:[1.11,1.12).
  Required by:
      org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.2.0
> Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_messages:tf2_msgs:[0.5,0.6).
  Required by:
      org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.2.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
make[2]: *** [rosjava_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rosjava_core/CMakeFiles/gradle-rosjava_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

what should i do? it is normal error?
please help.

Tal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197236/compile-rosjava/) by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2014-11-11**:
Of course, this is not normal. Have you followed all the steps carefully? When does the failure occur? Is it during `catkin_make` command? In case, the other previous steps have ended correctly?

**Comment by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on 2014-11-11**:
during `catkin_make`. i do all the steps. all other command ended correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just delete all the rosjava folder and just do it again from begin, and it work.
maybe the git was updated?
maybe i install more sdk? then it work?

I am not really sure. but now it working.

---

It happen me again when i just delete some file from devel folder.

Make sure you close all app in the computer. this compilation is hard job, and if it stop at the middle, you probable

get this errors messages.

then just delete build and devel folder in ~/rosjava folder, then catkin_make.

good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) with karma: 108 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0